# Is there a ppa or debian package for Thunderbird 3.3a?

Tags: ppa, thunderbird

I'm trying to find a debian installer for Thunderbird 3.3 (in development) or a ppa. I couldn't find any ppas, but I'm guessing someone must have created one by now :D. Anyone know where I can get one?

Please do not suggest the mozilla-daily ppa, I'm using it, but for some reason they stopped adding the newest thunderbird builds at 3.1 (that ppa is odd like that).

Comment: I am also looking for this. Anyone wanting to use the conversation view add-on (so thunderbird looks like gmail) will want to get their hands on 3.3, since it does NOT work with thunderbird 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thunderbird 3.3 alpha 2 is now available here: https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-next

Thunderbird 3.3 dailies are available here: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa

Comment: Thanks :D! I found this yesterday in another question's answer and I'm totally excited :D